# mysqli and bind_param - what parameters can be used?

Tags: php, data-binding, mysqli, bind

Could anybody confirm the first two statements below are good and the last one is wrong:

Invalid:

```
$sql="SELECT Code, Name FROM Country WHERE Code LIKE ? LIMIT 5";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", "C%");
```

Invalid:

```
$sql="SELECT Code, Name FROM Country WHERE Code LIKE ? LIMIT 5";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare();
$stmt->bind_param("s", strtolower($_POST['code']));
```

Invalid (binding more than just literal values):

```
$sql="SELECT Code, Name FROM Country ? LIMIT 5";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare();
$stmt->bind_param("s", "WHERE Code LIKE C%");
```

Valid:

```
$sql="SELECT Code, Name FROM Country WHERE Code LIKE ? LIMIT 5";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare();
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['code']);
```

I'm asking it because I want to understand Mysqli Prepared Statements basic properly.

I'm still not sure what parameters I can put into `bind_param()`. Can I put not variables, but its values (my first example) or even execute some php functions (my second example) as parameters in bind_param()?

[php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) says `bool mysqli_stmt::bind_param ( string $types , mixed &$var1 [, mixed &$... ] )`

But that's still not clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I put not variables, but its values (my first example)

You can't. that's the problem.

> I want to understand Mysqli Prepared Statements basic properly.

Don't waste your time, learn **[PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)** Prepared Statements instead.
They are a lot more sensible and usable.
it has `bindValue()` method which will allow you everything you mentioned above

In case you have to use mysqli API - there is a solution too, you can use [SafeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) built on top of mysqli

Comment: I'd better agree with you, but I'm not a boss regarding this question. That's for the project that uses mysqli.

Comment: Sorry it is still not clear for me. I've added the fourth example to my question. Am I right, 1-3 examples are invalid and the only 4th example is valid?

Answer (score -1):

For you first example you have added the `%` in your `bind_param` function. when your sql query is executed the `%` will be stored as a normal string and will not change the function of your statement.

For you second example, you would better do this :

```
$string = strtolower($_POST['code']);
$sql="SELECT Code, Name FROM Country WHERE Code LIKE ? LIMIT 5";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare();
$stmt->bind_param("s", $string);
```

For your third example, `bind_param` converts values to "things" that can be passed down to your database and does not allow altering your sql statment, aka sql injection. By the way, your first examples does the same with the `%` thing.

For your fourth example, it is valid because it is a variable with not function surrounding it. just like my second examples.

Hope this helps :)